# How to execute ansible playbook with sudo privilege

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I've got a problem with running ansible-playbook

See below my playbook

```
---
- hosts: some_group
  remote_user: someuser
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to remote nodes
    copy: src=/root/ansible/someimage dest=/home/someuser/

  - name: Load exported file of nginx image
    command: docker load -i /home/someuser/someimage
```

The command in terminal is:

**`ansible-playbook test.yml --ask-pass -K`**

ansible version is 2.0.0.2

The error is : "stderr": "Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:

Comment: I have an user on remote host for example: meiram and this user can use sudo.

Comment: Ok, so `docker` command says the permission was denied. What have you done to verify it's an Ansible problem and not a Docker configuration one?

Comment: I tried to use sudo docker images on the remote host.
Command was executed succeessfully

Comment: Ok, are you sure you are trying to connect to the same Docker engine? Any environment variables in use?

Comment: I didn't use variables. Manually on the remote host i can load image using sudo with password.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you understood the limitations when [becoming an unprivileged user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user). I would try to avoid this.

Instead you can work as privileged user. You just have to fix the permissions.

```
---
- hosts: some_group
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Copy file to remote nodes
    copy: src=/root/ansible/someimage dest=/home/someuser/someimage

  - name: Set permisions
    file: 
      dest: /home/someuser/someimage
      owner: someuser
      group: someuser
      mode: 0644

  - name: Load exported file of nginx image
    command: sudo someuser docker load -i /home/someuser/someimage
```